# Injecting command line arguments in an Ada AUnit test

Tags: command-line-arguments, ada, property-injection, aunit

I would like to inject command line arguments in an Ada AUnit test so that the design under test could receive proper Ada.Command_Line property values.

Concrete example: GHDL's [procedure Main](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/blob/336786f7651eb139538cc96a9ddc5c5f6bc93507/src/ghdldrv/ghdlmain.adb#L583) receives command line arguments, and I would like to test invocations such as

```
ghdl_mcode -r --workdir=/home/test test1
```

I can obviously hack around, but I am looking for a canonical, "official", general AUnit way to do this, if such a solution exists, without modifying the source code.

Comment: The source of Ada.Command_Line’s spec contains [these comments](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/add995ec117d756e61d207041cd32f937c1a1cd9/gcc/ada/libgnat/a-comlin.ads#L88); I’d expect that something could be written to take advantage of that. You might think of that as "hacking around", of course.

Comment: @SimonWright Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately this requires a C main function, and I would like to avoid that for now, so it is easier to just modify the Ada consumer directly. (I am curious though why a simple injector solution does not exist for Ada, when other languages literally have multiple implementations...)

Comment: Having tried to follow up on my comment above, I have to report failure. Ada.Command_Line has become (IMHO) inextricably dependent on the initialization code generated when a main program is bound, possibly so as to support the 3 extensions found [here](https://docs.adacore.com/live/wave/gnat_rm/html/gnat_rm/gnat_rm/the_gnat_library.html#ada-command-line-environment-a-colien-ads). I would imagine this is because AdaCore customers have asked/paid for these extensions, but not the extension you want.

Comment: Out of interest, can you point to examples of the multiple implementations offered by other languages?

Comment: Looking at the GCC history, Ada.Command_Line has had these extensions for >23 years! Live & learn

Comment: @SimonWright: Re: Dependency injection (constructor/setter/property injectors): Java had J2EE CDI (and reference implementation Weld), Spring, Guice (these I know, and they work well), but Google search shows that there is also Dagger, Feather, HK2, Netflix Governator, etc. For C++ you have boost:di/boost::ext_DI, kangaru (IOC/DI), and many short-lived projects. Crates.io (Rust) has 415 hits on "dependency injection". Easy DI and IOC is a major requirement on modern projects for easy test scaffolding and code decoupling, and so I am surprised ADA has apparently no DI and IOC solutions.